# javafx and scene builder

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
PieChart pie = new PieChart();
pie.setData(getChart());
StackPane pane = new StackPane();
Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
stage.setScene(scene);
pane.getChildren().addAll(pie);
stage.show();
}
private ObservableList<PieChart.Data> getChart() {
    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    list.addAll(new PieChart.Data("java",20), new PieChart.Data("c",20), 
    new PieChart.Data("C++",20));
    return list;
}
```

i want this chart to be displayed on scene builder. how is it possible..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: pie]

In SceneBuilder, from the menu:

1. Select `File | Open`
2. Choose pie.fxml
3. Select `View | Show Sample Data`

*pie.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<StackPane id="StackPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <children>
    <PieChart id="PieChart" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" />
  </children>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: i am sorry to ask this. could u help me with a step by step process for the solved answer. i m a basic to javaFX n scene builder. if u can provide me ur mail_id it wud b better. i can clarify my doubts when ur available. my id srini26juin@yahoo.com